grub failed to install to the following devices: /dev/sda6 Do you want to continue? your computer may not start up properly
After I ran sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y this error showed up:
GRUB failed to install to the following devices: /dev/sda6  
Do you want to continue anyway? If you do, your computer may not start up properly.  
Writing GRUB to boot device failed - continue?   

What should I do? is this risky to proceed? I am not dual booting. Should I create bootable USB in case I need an Ubuntu live USB?
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x0006, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
    Product Name: HP ProBook 4445s
    Version: A1018C1100
    Serial Number: 2CE322087Y
    UUID: 98d6c96e-c6b7-11e2-9673-ce39e79cba0e
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: QF682AV#UUF
    Family: 103C_5336AN G=N L=BUS B=HP S=PRO

Handle 0x0009, DMI type 32, 20 bytes
System Boot Information
    Status: No errors detected


UEFI or old BIOS install? You never install grub to a partition like sda6, you would install to sda if that is correct drive. But if newer system after 2012, probably UEFI and you should have gpt partitioning with one partition as the ESP - efi system partition. When you specify a drive, system knows UEFI boot files go into the partition specified as the ESP during install. How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs. What version/flavor of Ubuntu? What brand/model system?

I am scared, I don't know what to do. Would installing grub delete my work files? I feel I can't even shut down my laptop now.
the version is updated in the main post.

You data cannot be valuable, if you do not have good backups. Systems fail, SSD can crash without notice, HDD only sometimes behaved strangely to let you know they were about to crash. My newish Dell would not charge & I had to totally reinstall everything after motherboard replacement. Users make mistakes (even those of use that should know better). You need good backups & a live installer or repair/recovery drive for every system you have installed. HP usually requires you to set boot order in UEFI settings, not UEFI boot menu. And grub has to be correctly installed for system to boot it.

Looks like your system is older, originally old DOS drive with BIOS Windows. If you installed in BIOS boot mode, grub must be installed to MBR or sectors before first partition. You specify drive, not a partition. If you have converted to gpt (recommended) you have to have a bios_grub partition for grub to correctly install in BIOS mode. But conversion from MBR to gpt totally erases drive, so backups required. I started booting Ubuntu in BIOS mode from gpt back in 2010. But old systems work better with light weight flavors. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours

There are a lot of posts here about this error message and none seem to have a very good answer. Is this a system you've been using for a while and this error just suddenly showed up? Anyway, this shouldn't destroy your data, but if your system won't boot, you would have to use a live USB to boot it and get to the data. If your computer is still working, before doing anything else, I suggest backing up your data. I also think there is a good change boot-repair will fix this, but back up first.
